# Perform a head on mysqldump at the same time as piping to mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, tee

On Ubuntu 14.04 terminal using bash, i'm able to dump from master mysql db to the slave:

```
mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 --user=myuser --password=[password] --host=127.0.0.1 mydb | mysql --max_allowed_packet=128M -h 192.168.1.110 -u myuser -p[password] otherdb
```

But I simultaneously want to redirect the mysqldump output to `head -30 > /tmp/pointintime.log` so I can get the point in time info:

```
--
-- Position to start replication or point-in-time recovery from
--

-- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.049868', MASTER_LOG_POS=107;
```

How to do this? I tried using `tee` but this results in sql syntax errors at the slave import end (as though its breaking up the output and not sending full statements):

```
mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 --user=myuser --password=[password] --host=127.0.0.1 mydb | tee >(head -30 >/tmp/pointintime.log) | mysql --max_allowed_packet=128M -h 192.168.1.110 -u myuser -p[password] otherdb
```

How to `mysqldump` import to slave mysql db and simultaneously retrieve the `head -30` of the dump? I dont want to dump to a file first because the db is huge, its more efficient to pipe over the network.

I also tried using multiple `tee` redirects but had the same syntax error:

```
mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 --user=myuser --password=[password] --host=127.0.0.1 mydb | tee >(mysql --max_allowed_packet=128M -h 192.168.1.110 -u myuser -p[password] otherdb) >(head -30 >/tmp/pointintime.log)
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 47: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `tee` and `head` because `head` closes its input handle once it has output the requested number of lines, breaking the pipe.  Here's what you should see with the command you've written.

`mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write`

Error 32 is "Broken pipe."

The other error -- I suspect -- is because the broken pipe causes the input handle to `mysql` to be closed, with a partial line of output already written, and the end of file it receives when that happens is interpreted as a premature end of statement.

You need something in the middle that will not break the pipe.  Suggestion: the swiss army chainsaw... Perl.

Replace this:

```
| tee >(head -30 >/tmp/pointintime.log) |
```

With this:

```
| perl -p -e 'print STDERR $_ unless $. > 30' 2>/tmp/pointintime.log |
```

The `-e` switch tells Perl that instead of loading a Perl script from a file, that the script is inside the quoted string that follows.  The `-p` switch causes this little one-line "program" to be run for each line of STDIN, after which each input line will be printed to STDOUT, with the input line transiently appearing in the variable `$_` as each line passes through, and the variable `$.` indicating the running line counter.  Of course `STDERR` is the second output stream, which we catch with `2>` and redirect to your log file, and once `$. > 30` is true, no more lines are written to your log... but they're all written to the output.

Simple as that.

Piping mysqldump through Perl in this way is completely safe -- it will not manipulate the data in any way, it will write it out exactly as it came in.  I routinely do this when I need to modify a backup stream on the fly.

Comment: nice, appreciate the detailed explanation also.